# foreach results as feed_url

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach, simplexml

I'm trying to get the result of my foreach loop into an url to do a simplexml_load_file with.

So it goes like this:
(...) //SimpleXML_load_file to get $feed1

```
    $x=1;
    $count=$feed1->Count; //get a count for total number of loop from XML
    foreach ($feed1->IdList->Id as $item1){

    echo $item1;
    if($count > $x) {
    echo ',';} //Because I need coma after every Id, except the last one.
    $x++;
    }
```

The two echo are just to see the result. It gives me something like:

```
22927669,22039496,21326191,18396266,18295747,17360921,15705350,15681025,15254092,12939407,11943825,11495650,10964843
```

I would like to put that in a url to make a simplexml_load_file just like that

```
$feed_url = 'http://www.whatevergoeshere'. $RESULT_OF_FOREACH . 'someothertext';
```

So it would look like:

```
$feed_url = 'http://www.whatevergoeshere22927669,22039496,21326191,18396266,18295747,17360921,15705350,15681025,15254092,12939407,11943825,11495650,10964843someothertext';
```

I've try to store it into an array or a function and then call it into the feed_url but it did not work the way I tried it.

I hope it's clear, I'll answer fast to questions if not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really difficult to make out what you want, so I'm going to guess you want to store the list as a comma delimited string in a variable. the easiest way is to [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array of ids

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($feed1->IdList->Id as $item1){
    $ids[] = (string) $item1;
}
$RESULT_OF_FOREACH = implode(',', $ids);

$feed_url = 'http://www.whatevergoeshere'. $RESULT_OF_FOREACH . 'someothertext';
```

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer Crip. I want to store it as a comma delimited string in a variable. However imploding the array as you suggested doesn't seams to be working. I can't echo it or put it in the feed_url as well...

Comment: what does `var_dump($RESULT_OF_FOREACH)` reveal? can you perhaps pastebin the result?

Comment: Ok, try the above, basically building the array of ids first.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much, I've been struggling with that for a long time now.